# NoReverseMatch for all admin urls after upgrade to django 1.7

Tags: django, django-urls

I am in the process of upgrading huge project from Django 1.6.2 towards latest 1.8 version.

Following all release notes here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.7/#using-a-custom-manager-when-traversing-reverse-relations

I believe I revisited my entire project for backwards incompatibilities, but I am still getting this error on any reverse url call to any admin page.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
reverse('admin:scanners_scanner_changelist')

NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'scanners_scanner_changelist' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

This was working just fine on django 1.6.x

It's very frustrating as this error tells you nothing... Basically you have to guess and try what's wrong. Do any of you guys have some ideas what I might be missing, what is changed from Django 1.6 to 1.7 that could potentially cause this?

All other urls work fine except for admin changelist and change urls.

Comment: How are the admin urls being included in your project? The full traceback might show what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out. [django-adminplus](https://github.com/jsocol/django-adminplus) was a cause of this.

So if you are having similar problems when upgrading from Django 1.6.x to 1.7.x try to change `django.contrib.admin` to `django.contrib.admin.apps.SimpleAdminConfig` and do not remove `admin.autodiscover()` from your main urls.py file. This way you are doing admin discovery manually and explicitly, the old way instead of new implicit method which might cause you troubles if you are doing some serious hacking within  your project.

Cheers!